# SEO of tags and question titles

Tags: discussion

I just tried searching for a few of our questions that I know have a wider audience (for example questions on diet, smoking and pregnancy, exercise) on Google and Bing and we didn't show up very early. I think some of that may be related to unclear question titles that don't really summarize the question, and missing tags. Itt's just one part, of course, but something that is easily fixed, so I am gently going through a few questions and editing. Gently meaning not more than a few a day so the edits don't push new questions away too much.

Just a heads up in case you are wondering why I am editing even more than normal :-) Help is welcome.